# Flask Python inconsistent import variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import

I have a Flask application where I'm experiencing an issue where I have inconsistent importing. Basically whenever I run my tests, the app imports my router correctly in the `app.py` in the project root. However, whenever I import my router when I run my `app.py`. This is all verified by printing out available modules using `dir()`.

My error message is `NameError: name 'router' is not defined`

I have **init**.py files in each of my directories.

`project_root/app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from src.router import *

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`project_root/src/router.py`

```
from flask import request, Response, Blueprint

router = Blueprint('router', __name__)
```

When I run my tests using `APP_ENV=testing python3 -m unittest discover`, I see the following output as a `dir()`

`['Blueprint', 'Flask', 'Migrate', 'Response', ..., 'router']`

However, when running the `app.py`, I see the the same output without the router.

I made sure the `sys.path` are the same, so there aren't any inconsistencies with what paths are being checked.

Anybody have any clue why my tests would allow to import this variable and running it normally wouldn't work?

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I explicitly set it when running these commands to make sure they are they same. When running these files from the command line from the project root, I do `PYTHONPATH='.' python3 app.py` or when running tests `PYTHONPATH='.' python3 -m unittest discover`.